# How do I make Live Server start automatically when I open a VS Code project?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to make it so that when I open a project, I don't have to press the Live Server start button separately, but that it starts automatically. Is it even possible? I dug through all the documentation for both Live Server and VS Code and did not find how to do it. I'm sure I'm just dumb, and you can easily tell me how to do it.

tried to start @command:extension.liveServer.goOnline startup task
through the console, so that later I can write it into Task , I dug out "code --enable-proposed-api " in the VS Code documentation, but if I use it, what should I write inside? what is the API of the LiveServer extension? :
(https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line)

in general, my attempts are damned, don’t read them too much, they are more likely to knock you down. I need Live Server to start automatically when I open a VS Code project. How exactly - it doesn't matter